# Augment the Array type

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to augment `Array` as follows:

`Array.prototype.myFunction = function () { return 10; }`

But then, the following doesn't work:

`var myArray = "Bla"`
`myArray.myFunction();`

What's the stupid mistake I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `"Bla"` is not an `Array`. Its a `String`.